# Heroku Routes to backend not working in development mode

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I made a simple todo application with React,Node and Mongodb. The application works fine while run on the dev server. When I deploy it, however, it appears as though the app can't hit the todo API routes. Any help would be appreciated.
this is my github repo link(https://github.com/Ashish5911/notebook-backend/)

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you to identify the presence of errors in Heroku log for further analysis.

You can open the Heroku log by pressing the **View logs** button as seen in the below pop-up menu:

[image: View logs menu popup]

Answer (score 0):

.env is in your .gitignore file, which is what is not pushed to Heroku. If you remove .env from your .gitignore, that may help. I faced the same issue before.